# Passing a simple IEnumerable to view and using foreach to loop through returns a blank screen?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple List of Customer model class which I am passing to my view. I want to iterate through the customer class but my view is telling me to bugger off by returning a blank screen. Please tell me what is wrong here?

**Model Class:**

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**Home Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            Customer customer = new Customer() { FullName = "MrA" ,Age=25};
            Customer customer2 = new Customer() { FullName = "MrB", Age = 125 };
            return View(customers);
        }
```

**View HTML file**

```
@model IEnumerable<ASPMVC_Database.Models.Customer>
/...some unrelated code

  @foreach( var item in Model)
        {
            @item.FullName <br/>               

        }
```

This simple code above gives me nothing. Just a white screen. What am I missing out here?

Thank you

Comment: Is it supposed to show up anything else besides the list like common elements from layout template?

Comment: No , I just want to see MrA and MrB printed on two lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add the new customers to `customers`, you simple instantiate them. Try the following instead:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    customers.Add(new Customer { FullName = "MrA", Age = 25});
    customers.Add(new Customer { FullName = "MrB", Age = 125 });
    return View(customers);
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot that i was supposed to add that...THANKS! will accept in 10min

Comment: No worries. When that happens to be I have one of two options: Another [bawls](http://www.bawls.com) or sleep (though usually the first).