# Return not only one, but many data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I've got this nice list in my View, and it has many values, so how can I like merge all the values and return it to my Controller?

```
<ul>
    <li>Alex</li>
    <li>Bobby</li>
    <li>Camilla</li>
    <li>Denise</li>
    <li>Elise</li>
    <li>Francis</li>
</ul>
```

Edit

My View is like, I have a textbox to enter a name, then I click the "add" button, and it's added in the list by jQuery.

So when the add button is clicked, I'd like to send all names to the Controller

Comment: IEnumerable<Names> names  and then bind them in the view with foreach check out this answer it might helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931904/passing-a-simple-ienumerable-to-view-and-using-foreach-to-loop-through-returns-a

Answer (score 0):

You need to put those itens inside a form on your view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <ul>
      <li>Alex<input type="hidden" name="names" value="Alex"></li>
      <li>Bobby<input type="hidden" name="names" value="Bobby"></li>
      <li>Camilla<input type="hidden" name="names" value="Camilla"></li>
      <li>Denise<input type="hidden" name="names" value="Denise"></li>
      <li>Elise<input type="hidden" name="names" value="Elise"></li>
      <li>Francis<input type="hidden" name="names" value="Francis"></li>
   </ul>
   <button type="submit">GOO</button>
}
```

then on your controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(List<string> names)
  {

     return View();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but my View is like, I have a textbox to enter a name, then click the "add" button, and it's added in the list, and when the add button is clicked, I'd like to send all names to the Controller

Comment: @PatrickFritch just apped the html on your list with the hidden field exactly  like the example I posted